# Or statement in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, where-clause

I have a very silly question,
I want to select count rows where `id_employe` is 0 OR 1 in pdo, and i'm not sure how to do it
This is what i did :

```
$connexion = connexion();
$request_travail = $connexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS heures FROM plannings WHERE id_employe = ? AND id_affectation = ? OR id_affectation = ? AND id_validation = ?");

$resultat = $request_travail->execute(array($vendeur, 0, 1, 1));
$heures = $resultat->heures;
```

And also, is it ok to use count like above?

Comment: FYI: PDO doesn't execute your queries. It does a database server, assuming mysql

Comment: AND and OR have a different order of precedence.  use parens to override default order.  we could avoid the OR using IN e.g.  `... AND id_affectation IN ( ? , ? ) AND ...`

Answer (score 2):

Your need parentheses around the `OR`ed conditions, because boolean operator `OR` has lowest precedence than `AND`:

```
WHERE id_employe = ? 
  AND (id_affectation = ? OR id_affectation = ?)
  AND id_validation = ?
```

But this is simpler expressed with `IN`:

```
WHERE id_employe = ? 
  AND id_affectation IN (?, ?)
  AND id_validation = ?
```